# $f: X \to Y$ is continuous iff for every open $V \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ question about iff

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces. I have a question about one of the directions of the proof. Here it goes:

Suppose that $\forall$ open $V \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. Show that $f : X \to Y$ is continuous.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Let $x \in X$. Then $B_{\epsilon}(f(x))$ is open in $Y$. By hypothesis, $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(f(x)))$ is open in $X$. $x \in f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(f(x)))$. Therefore, $\exists$ $\delta >0$ such that $B_{\delta}(x) \subseteq f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(f(x)))$ or that $f(B_{\delta}(x)) \subseteq B_{\epsilon}(f(x))$. Hence, $f$ is continuous.

So the question is: Y could be a metric space that has no open sets. So how do we know an open $B_{\epsilon}(f(x))$ exists in $Y$?

Thank you.

Comment: For any space $Y$, the whole space and the empty set are always open. So how can there be a space without open sets? Also for a metric space, the topology is the one induced by the metric, which is precisely the topology generated by $B_\epsilon(y)$ for all $y\in Y$ and $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Interestingly, this "inverse image of an open set is open" property is the definition of continuity used in topology.

Comment: @user125261: In many textbooks it is *not* taken as the definition. Continuity is defined pointwise ($f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if for each open nbhd $U$ of $f(x)$ in $Y$ there is an open nbhd $V$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f[V]\subseteq U$), and the characterization here is a theorem (or exercise).